# Notepad++ Inquiry Text Only

Tags: notepad++, source-code

I'm currently using Notepad++ to alter the source code of a document and I was wondering if it was possible to view only the black text, rather than having to go through it section by section and just ignore the other characters.

[image: imgur.com/a/YGI0h]

Comment: I don't think it's possible - although you could fiddle with the xml stye colours and change the colours of all tags to the background colour ...

Comment: Ok, think I may have found a compromise by inserting the text I want changed into the 'Search' and 'Replace' function.